# WordPress Plugin Conflict with WooCommerce Product Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Our plugin displays a red signup bar across the entire site.  On the Woo Commerce pages only, the signup bar is going into the Product Description Container as shown here:

[image: Incorrect Position]

---

This is what it should be doing, consistent with the rest of the site:

[image]

---

Here is a code extract from the plugin:

---

```css
/*Style sheet for the Signup Plugin
Teresa Light August 16, 2015
Version 1.0
*/

#main.clearfix.width-100{
    padding-right:0px!important;
    padding-left:0px!important;
}

/* Overall Container */
signup  {
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto 0px!important;
  font-size:80%;
  background: #d03925;
  text-align: center;  
  display: flex;  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
/* Begin Flex */
.flex-container {
  text-align: center;  
  display: flex;  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
   -webkit-align-items: center;
   align-items: center;
   -webkit-justify-content: center;
   justify-content: center;
}

/* MOBIL FIRST */
.flex-container{
   flex-direction: column;
   -webkit-box-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-box-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  margin:0 0 5px 0;
  padding:15px;
}

/* DESKTOPS - go to a row for screens greater than 1000px */ 
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .flex-container{
   flex-direction: row;
   -webkit-box-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-box-flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  margin:0 10px;
  padding:10px 0;
  }
}
/* End  Flex */

h3.signup-message, .signup-message{
  margin: auto;
  padding:0;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500; 
  text-align:right;
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:30px;
}

#inf_field_FirstName, #inf_field_Email {
  border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
  color: #747474;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  width: 270px;
}

.ccg-button {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#ffffff;
    background: #d03925;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size:15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 13px 30px 13px 30px;
}
.ccg-button:hover, .ccg-button:focus, .ccg-button:active{
    border-width:2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#d03925;
    color:#d03925;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: ccg-signup
Description:  Adds an eye-catching signup bar to the bottom of the page
Author: Teresa Light
Author URI: https://teresalight.com
Plugin URI: 
Version: 1.0
License: 
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

// Register style sheet.
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_plugin_styles' );

/**
 * Register style sheet.
 */

  function register_plugin_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'ccg-signup', plugins_url( 'ccg-signup/css/signup-bar.css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'ccg-signup' );
    }

    add_filter( 'the_content', 'signup_bar' );

    function signup_bar($content){

$content.='';
$content.='
 <signup>
   <form>

     <div class="flex-container">
      <h3 class="signup-message">Get tips to start, fund and grow Your Great Business:</h3>
     </div> 

     <div class="flex-container">
      <input id="inf_field_FirstName"  name="inf_field_FirstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name*">
     </div>

    <div class="flex-container">
     <input style="margin:10px 0;"id="inf_field_Email" name="inf_field_Email" type="text" placeholder="Email*">
    </div>

    <div class="flex-container">
     <input class="input.flex-container ccg-button" type="submit" value="START NOW">
    </div>
   </form>
 </signup>';
$content.='';
return $content;
    }

// Omit closing PHP tag to avoid "Headers already sent" issues.
```

---

A ticket was submitted to both Themeforest and WooCommerce however I am not optimistic about receiving a fix from either since it is our plugin.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: Hi @user2502479. Can you share any styles that might be attached to that componet

Answer (score 2):

I have never worked with WooCommerce, but from what I can tell your signup bar comes directly after the content. It looks like the bar gets attached to the content, which for WooCommerce seems to be the product itself.

Maybe you want to instead hook the signup bar to the action before the contact us section instead. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: I now have it working on the Woo Commerce page but not the rest of the site so that is progress!

Comment: This code has it working on Woo Commerce but NOT the rest of the site.  I believe that the action before the "contact us" section varies by the page but I did not pursue that yet.  This works but not on the main pages (yet):  Thank you for the help.remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);

add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'signup_bar', 10);

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'signup_bar', 10);

Comment: Thank you!  It now works well BUT it it is the last below the footer.  I don't know how to make it come up first so I'm researching that now.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than filtering the_content why not use wp_footer to ensure your signup bar is at the bottom of the page. WooCommerce loads custom content wrapper header and footers which may be affecting your layout.

Another option is to additionally load your plugin at the bottom of a woocommerce page using the hook woocommerce_after_main_content

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/

Comment: I substituted this action for the footer and now it does not display.  I might need more code around it.  The Woocommerce page looks complex but I guess I might need to go to that.  Any help with the entire code snippet I might try would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'signup_bar' );

/*    add_filter( 'the_content', 'signup_bar' );*/

Comment: It is now working consistently on all pages but after the footer so now I just need to figure out how to get it to be first in the footer.

Comment: Try changing the priority which the action is added. Also inspect the source with dev tools. Or open footer.php and check if an actino hook exists higher up in that template file which you could use other than wp_footer

Comment: Anagio, any help on a final solution would be really appeciated.    I reposted this here with the new but related problem that usinjg wp-footer causes along with the footer.php file.  I:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160743/wp-footer-hook-puts-content-below-footer '