# wp_footer hook puts content below footer

Tags: wordpress

My custom plugin to put a red sign-up bar just above the footer is putting it at the bottom of the footer using wp_footer.  If I use the the_content in a filter, then it puts it into the description of the Woo Commerce product pages.  Does anyone know of a way to move this action from the bottom to the top of the footer inside of the plugin? I have tried many combinations of things and am just getting no where.  Thank you for helping.

[image: Photo where Red Bar is on bottom and not top of footer]

**Signup Bar Plugin**

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: ccg-signup
Description:  Adds an eye-catching signup bar to the bottom of the page
Author: Teresa Light
Author URI: https://teresalight.com
Plugin URI: 
Version: 1.0
License: 
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

/**
 * Register style sheet.
 */

   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_plugin_styles' );


  function register_plugin_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'ccg-signup', plugins_url( 'ccg-signup/css/signup-bar.css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'ccg-signup' );
    }

/**
 * Add HTML markup for the bar
 */

    function signup_bar($content){
    ?>  <!-- /** Use this to end PHP for the action hook test.  Add the next line for the php variable instead.*/ -->

            <signup>
                    <form class="flex-container" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST" action="https://eu943.infusionsoft.com/app/form/process/ae41b9e4b0750e3e3aa3ae78337d5fa6">
                        <input name="inf_form_xid" type="hidden" value="ae41b9e4b0750e3e3aa3ae78337d5fa6">
                        <input name="inf_form_name" type="hidden" value="CCG Newsletter Sign Up">
                        <input name="infusionsoft_version" type="hidden" value="1.38.0.37">

                        <div class="flex-container">
                            <h3 class="signup-message">Get tips to start, fund and grow Your Great Business:</h3>
                        </div> 

                        <div class="flex-container">
                            <input id="inf_field_FirstName"  name="inf_field_FirstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name*">
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex-container">
                            <input style="margin:10px 0;"id="inf_field_Email" name="inf_field_Email" type="text" placeholder="Email*">
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex-container">
                            <input class="input.flex-container ccg-button" type="submit" value="START NOW">
                        </div>
                    </form>
            </signup>
    <?php
    }
// Omit closing PHP tag to avoid "Headers already sent" issues.
// EXTRA CODE BELOW SHOWING PAST TRIALS, CURRENTLY COMMENTED OUT
/* The next two lines of code when used with the HTML based function will put the bar in the right place on Woo pages only */
/*remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 1);
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'signup_bar', 1);
 */

/* This line of code will put the signup bar correct on normal pages but in the description on the woo pages. It only works when the function code is totally inside of php */
/*add_filter( 'the_content', 'signup_bar',1 );*/


/*The code below works correctly on all pages but at the bottom of the footer, and not the top.*/
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'signup_bar', 1);
```

**Signup Bar CSS**

```
#main.clearfix.width-100{
    padding-right:0px!important;
    padding-left:0px!important;
}

/* Overall Container */
signup  {
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto 0px!important;
  font-size:80%;
  background: #d03925;
  text-align: center;  
  display: flex;  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
/* Begin Flex */
.flex-container {
  text-align: center;  
  display: flex;  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
   -webkit-align-items: center;
   align-items: center;
   -webkit-justify-content: center;
   justify-content: center;
}

/* MOBIL FIRST */
.flex-container{
   flex-direction: column;
   -webkit-box-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-box-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  margin:0 0 5px 0;
  padding:15px;
}

/* DESKTOPS - go to a row for screens greater than 1000px */ 
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .flex-container{
   flex-direction: row;
   -webkit-box-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-box-flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  margin:0 10px;
  padding:10px 0;
  }
}
/* End  Flex */

h3.signup-message, .signup-message{
  margin: auto;
  padding:0;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500; 
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:30px;
}

#inf_field_FirstName, #inf_field_Email {
  border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
  color: #747474;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  width: 270px;
}

.ccg-button {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#ffffff;
    background: #d03925;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size:15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 13px 30px 13px 30px;
}
.ccg-button:hover, .ccg-button:focus, .ccg-button:active{
    border-width:2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#d03925;
    color:#d03925;
    background: #ffffff;
}
/************** END SIGNUP BAR ******************/
```

**THEME FOOTER.PHP**

```
                </div>  <!-- fusion-row -->
            </div>  <!-- #main -->

            <?php
            global $social_icons;

            if ( strpos( Avada()->settings->get( 'footer_special_effects' ), 'footer_sticky' ) !== FALSE ) {
                echo '</div>';
            }

            // Get the correct page ID
            $c_pageID = Avada::c_pageID();

            // Only include the footer
            if ( ! is_page_template( 'blank.php' ) ) {

                $footer_parallax_class = '';
                if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'footer_special_effects' ) == 'footer_parallax_effect' ) {
                    $footer_parallax_class = ' fusion-footer-parallax';
                }

                echo sprintf( '<div class="fusion-footer%s">', $footer_parallax_class );

                    // Check if the footer widget area should be displayed
                    if ( ( Avada()->settings->get( 'footer_widgets' ) && get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'pyre_display_footer', true ) != 'no' ) ||
                         ( ! Avada()->settings->get( 'footer_widgets' ) && get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'pyre_display_footer', true ) == 'yes' )
                    ) {
                    ?>
                        <footer class="fusion-footer-widget-area">
                            <div class="fusion-row">
                                <div class="fusion-columns fusion-columns-<?php echo Avada()->settings->get( 'footer_widgets_columns' ); ?> fusion-widget-area">

                                    <?php
                                    // Check the column width based on the amount of columns chosen in Theme Options
                                    $column_width = 12 / Avada()->settings->get( 'footer_widgets_columns' );
                                    if( Avada()->settings->get( 'footer_widgets_columns' ) == '5' ) {
                                        $column_width = 2;
                                    }

                                    // Render as many widget columns as have been chosen in Theme Options
                                    for ( $i = 1; $i < 7; $i++ ) {
                                        if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'footer_widgets_columns' ) >= $i ) {
                                            echo sprintf( '<div class="fusion-column col-lg-%s col-md-%s col-sm-%s">', $column_width, $column_width, $column_width );

                                                if ( function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) &&
                                                     dynamic_sidebar( 'avada-footer-widget-' . $i )
                                                ) {
                                                    // All is good, dynamic_sidebar() already called the rendering
                                                }
                                            echo '</div>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ?>

                                    <div class="fusion-clearfix"></div>
                                </div> <!-- fusion-columns -->
                            </div> <!-- fusion-row -->
                        </footer> <!-- fusion-footer-area -->
                    <?php
                    } // end footer wigets check

                    // Check if the footer copyright area should be displayed
                    if ( ( Avada()->settings->get( 'footer_copyright' ) && get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'pyre_display_copyright', true ) != 'no' ) ||
                          ( ! Avada()->settings->get( 'footer_copyright' ) && get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'pyre_display_copyright', true ) == 'yes' )
                    ) {
                    ?>
                        <footer id="footer" class="fusion-footer-copyright-area">
                            <div class="fusion-row">
                                <div class="fusion-copyright-content">

                                    <?php
                                    /**
                                     * avada_footer_copyright_content hook
                                     *
                                     * @hooked avada_render_footer_copyright_notice - 10 (outputs the HTML for the Theme Options footer copyright text)
                                     * @hooked avada_render_footer_social_icons - 15 (outputs the HTML for the footer social icons)
                                     */
                                    do_action( 'avada_footer_copyright_content' );
                                    ?>

                                </div> <!-- fusion-fusion-copyright-area-content -->
                            </div> <!-- fusion-row -->
                        </footer> <!-- #footer -->
                    </div> <!-- fusion-footer -->
                <?php
                } // end footer copyright area check
            } // end is not blank page check
            ?>
        </div> <!-- wrapper -->

        <?php
        // Check if boxed side header layout is used; if so close the #boxed-wrapper container
        if ( ( ( Avada()->settings->get( 'layout' ) == 'Boxed' && get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'pyre_page_bg_layout', true ) == 'default' ) || get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'pyre_page_bg_layout', true ) == 'boxed' ) &&
             Avada()->settings->get( 'header_position' ) != 'Top'

        ) {
        ?>
            </div> <!-- #boxed-wrapper -->
        <?php
        }

        ?>

        <!-- W3TC-include-js-head -->

        <?php
        wp_footer();

        // Echo the scripts added to the "before </body>" field in Theme Options
        echo Avada()->settings->get( 'space_body' );
        ?>

        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/js/respond.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </body>
</html>
```

**THANK YOU**

Answer (score 1):

`wp_footer()` is to be called right before `</body>` and is NOT the function for getting the themes footer.  You are looking for `get_footer()`  However, many themes do not actually use `get_footer()`, so if you are looking for mass distribution, that will not be a very reliable method.  That said, some themes don't use `wp_footer()` either.

Comment: I tried substituting get_footer for wp_footer and the bar did not display at all.  I'll try that again.  There must be a way to put a red bar above a footer without impacting woo commerce by using the_content filter.  Any help for a solution to do this would be really appreciated.

Comment: I'd say check your theme to make sure it's actually using `get_footer()`

Comment: It does because this is the last line of the archive.php and in others: <?php get_footer();  Does that mean I cannot use it in my plugin?  Or am I using it incorrectly?  I tried this:  add_action( 'get_footer', 'signup_bar', 1);   It resulted in the footer being displayed but not the signup_bar.  Any ideas?

Comment: I put the php for the footer in a separate file and then put this in the plugin file:  get_footer('signup_bar/includes/signup-bar-footer.php');  It wouldn't activate due to errors.  I think it conflicted with the theme's use of get_footer.  There must be a way to put a bar above the footer without using the filter the_content.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I would need to tinker with your specific theme.  I don't use woocommerce, is it woocommerce directly, or is it a child theme?

Comment: My code is in a plugin.  WooCommerce is also a plugin.  The child theme is default.  Maybe I should try it on the 2015 theme.  There must be a way to hook in a container at the top of the footer versus the bottom without relying on the specific filter called the_content that the other plugin uses.  I assume it is possible to use get_footer twice on one page since different arguments are passed but maybe not.  Then I need some other action hook to get it to go to the top of the footer.  Thank you for helping.  I really appreciate it.  It's very frustrating because I'm sure it's been done.